# How to use event listener to submit button

Tags: javascript, html, function, methods, addeventlistener

i've some trouble with this event listener. I'm tryng to add an event listener in the submit button, but it doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong!
This is my work:

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{​​​​
let valid = true;
valid=valida();
if(!valid){
e.preventDefault();
}
});
function valida() {
var nome = document.getElementById("nome");
const nomeVal = nome.value;
var cognome = document.getElementById("cognome");
const cVal = cognome.value;
let valida = true; 
valida = nomeVal.length < 8 ? setError(nome, "devi inserire nome"): setSuccess(nome);
if (cVal.length < 8) {
 valida = setError(cognome, "devi inserire cognome");
}
return valida;
}
function setError(input, m) {
input.className = "error"
const ciao = input.nextElementSibling;
ciao.innerText = m;
return false;
}
function setSuccess(input) {
input.className = 'success';
const error = input.nextElementSibling;
error.innerText = '';
return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" name="registrazione" action="index.html" >
Nome: <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text"> <small></small><br>
Cognome: <input id="cognome" name="cognome" type="text"> <small></small>
<br>
<button id="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pasted your code into js fiddle.
There was a \u200b hidden character at the end of the 2nd line. Once I removed that it looks like it worked.
https://jsfiddle.net/mightypie/b1dmgtw2/9/

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried using onclick event handler?

Place the onlclick event in your submit button

```
<form id="form" name="registrazione" action="index.html" >
Nome: <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text"> <small></small><br>
Cognome: <input id="cognome" name="cognome" type="text"> <small></small>
<br>
<button id="button" onclick="test()" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

then on your js you can use the below code:

```
function test() {
let valid = true;
valid=valida();
if(!valid){
e.preventDefault();
}
};
```

Comment: I know it, but i  I would like to use the listener